# How specific are Vitamin D promotors in the DNA?

Tags: dna

As far as I understand there are genes that get regulated by the amount of Vitamin D that comes in contact with DNA. How specific are those promoters? Are there promotors that for example only get activated by calcifediol but not by calcitriol or cholecalciferol?

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/19944755/

Comment: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/m/pubmed/21397016/

Comment: I’ll try and turn those into an answer later.